# Make an item in a list active

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular ng-repeat:

```
  <div data-ng-controller="TestimonialClipController">

    <ul class="pager">
      <li data-ng-repeat="testimonial in model.testimonials">
        <a href="" data-ng-click="show($index)"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- remaining code -->

  </div>
```

When I click an anchor A I would like its class to become "active".

How can I do this? Do I need to add a variable to scope?

Comment: do you need to use `:active` or can you use your own class `.-active`?

Comment: @SamJacobs I can use my own class ...

Comment: okay see my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `var activeTestimonial = $index;` variable within your `TestimonialClipController`. Then do something like `<a ng-class="active: isActiveTestimonial($index)">...</a>`, where you have a method `$scope.isActiveTestimonial = function ($index) { ... }` which compares `$index` with `activeTestimonial`.

Your other option is to convert your list into a directive, and then work directly with the element.

`<my-testimonials data="{{model.testimonials}}"></my-testimonials>`

```
app.directive('myTestimonials', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ul class="pager">' +
            '<li data-ng-repeat="testimonial in testimonials">' +
                '<a href="" ng-click="show($event)">...</a>' +
            '</li>' + 
        '</ul>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.testimonials = attrs && attrs.data ? attrs.data || {};
        scope.show = show;      

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function show ($event) {
            elem.find('a').removeClass('active');
            $event.target.addClass('active');           
        }
    }
};
```

You could then work your way around the element chain using `elem.find('a')`, and this would be an action within your `show()` method.

For example:

1. User clicks a link, this triggers the `ng-click="show($event)"` method;
2. Within your `function show ($event) { ... }` method, you will first remove `.active` class from all links: `elem.find('a').removeClass('active');`
3. Now add `active` class to the current link that was clicked using something like `function show ($event) { ... }`, and then `$event.target.addClass('active')`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestimonialClipController">

    <ul class="pager">
      <li data-ng-repeat="testimonial in model.testimonials">
        <a href="" data-ng-click="show(testimonial)" ng-class="{'active':testimonial.active}"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      app.controller('TestimonialClipController',function($scope,$log) {
        $scope.model.testimonials = []
        $scope.show = function(testimonial) {
          testimonial.active = !testimonial.active
        }
      })
    </script>

  </div>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/j3htG9O05FDqfusC3XG5?p=preview

The ng-class gets compiled by angular into classes on your element. Where testimonial.active is truthy, the class active gets added to the element.

If all elements are going to start inactive and then become active on click then you may need to initialise the active or set it using your web server if appropriate.

ng-class:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

In the `show($index)` method you can set `$scope.selectedIndex = $index`, then use ng-class to set your own `.-active` class if `$scope.selectedIndex == $index`

Comment: pretty much what all the other answers are saying :P